# Is this a good instance for the Decorator design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

So I took an exam today in my intro to computer science course. One of the questions was on the Decorator design pattern and it gave me some trouble. My question is not about what the correct answer is but whether or not this is even a good instance to use the decorator pattern at all. Why decorate the person hierarchy when it would be just as easy and would require fewer classes to have the Population class calculate a persons BMI directly? Would a decorator really even add functionality in this case since BMI is a derived property of a Person objects state?

Question:

```
interface Person(){
    double getWeightInKG();
    double getHeightInMeters();
}
```

Given the person interface above use the decorator pattern to implement the Population class defined below. BMI is calculated using the formula BMI = weight(Kg) / height(meters)^2. You may have to design and implement other classes and interfaces to achieve this. Assume you have use of java.util.ArrayList.

```
+ Population: 
    - public void addPerson(Person p);
    - public void removePerson(Person p);
    - public double getAverageBMI();
    - public Person[ ] getPeopleInBMIRange(double bmi_min, bmi_max);
    - public int populationSize();
```

Comment: Because a "population" is a collection of people. It is not a calculator of BMI, nor should it be. I'm a little leery of having BMI-specific functionality in a population to begin with--seems more like information you'd filter *out* of a population.

Comment: @Dave, completely agree that BMI specific functionality shouldn't be in a population class.

Comment: I was a Java teacher so I understand the difficulty in creating simple, toy-domain assignments that use design patters. DP's are simply not a good fit for anything overly simplistic.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the decorator pattern to decorate the person. I would create a separate class for calculating the BMI that looks something like:

```
class BMICalculator {
    double getBMI(Person person) {}
}
```

Then I would use the BMICalculator in the Population class

```
class Population {
     private final BMICalculator calc;
     public double getAverageBMI() {
         double total = 0;
         for ( Person p : people ) {
            total += calc.getBMI(p);
         }
         return total/people.size();
     } 
}
```

I don't think decorator fits here.

Comment: So this would be called `Strategy`, I guess.

Comment: Not really Strategy pattern here. This is just object oriented programming, using another object to do the work it is designed to do.

Comment: If it isn't strategy then there is again little justification for that to even be an object. Why not a simple static method in that case? The point of having an object is dynamic dispatch, in this case to provide pluggable different implementations.

Comment: You could have a static method, sure. In general though that's harder to test. If you want to mock the BMI calculator, that's tougher to do.

Comment: Since this is such a toy domain, I guess that's a fair remark, since each of us can map BMI calculator to something else in the real world. But if you map it to just a function that calculates something, then there's no reason to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to define an interface, e.g. `BmiPerson extends Person { double bmi(); }`  and then aggregate these in the `Population`. So even though `BmiPerson` extends `Person`, it can still be implemented so as to contain another `Person` inside it -- a decorator. At least that's the best I can make of it. It still doesn't make a lot of sense since `Population` accepts `Person` and wouldn't know about the extra method in `BmiPerson`.

Comment: Yes, it does :) I updated the answer as you wrote the comment.

Comment: But the `Population` class would only be able to collect `BmiPerson`s then, assuming the `Population` BMI methods needed to access that information.

Comment: See my answer, I covered exactly that remark. Anyway, I gave the assignment its best shot. I really don't see how to better apply Decorator there.

Comment: yeah, this is how I answered the question, I just thought it seemed like a poor way to use this particular design pattern. the decorator pattern is best used to prevent a subclass explosion, but this doesn't seem to be a problem in this particular example.

Comment: Decorator is great when you want to change the behavior of already defined methods, not when you need to add new ones. Like for example Java's IO API.

Answer (score 0):

This question is garbage, for (at least) 2 reasons.

**1.** You can't apply the Decorator Pattern to an interface.  The
    goal of the pattern is to bolt new behavior onto some base
    functionality.  Interfaces don't have base functionality.

**2.** The other point of the pattern is that you can apply the new
    functionality on an object-by-object basis.  You would never have a
    `Person` whose BMI you wouldn't want to calculate.